# NPM install BCRYPT error: MSB8003

Tags: node.js, npm, cl.exe

I'm trying to install the **bcrypt** package with the command line

```
npm install bcrypt
```

But the prompt returns an error:

[image: error]

I've installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, i tried wth --msvs_version=2015 but i still had this error. Could you help me?

I'm using **Windows 10 x64**, **Node.js 0.12.7**, **npm 2.11.3** and **node-gyp 2.0.2**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the instruction properly given in node-gyp and bcrypt.
Which require proper python version , visual studio etc..

or you can also use

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs
```

Which doesnot have any depedency like vistual studio on Windows machine.